# How To Make Testimonial Automatic Slide Transition

Tags: jquery, css

I have this testimonial code below. It's all working fine except for the fact that I need to make it slide automatically instead of having the user click on each small round button to switch from one testimonial to another. So how do I make it run automatically, for instance like every 7 seconds the next testimonial slides in?

```css
/*** TestimonialS Slider - Free Weebly Widget by Baamboo Studio - Style 2 ***/
.testimonial_slider_2{
  width:100%;
  border: 0px solid #ebebeb;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}
.testimonial_slider_2 input {
  display: none;
}

.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_1:checked ~ .boo_inner { margin-left:0; }
.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_2:checked ~ .boo_inner { margin-left:-100%; }
.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_3:checked ~ .boo_inner { margin-left:-200%; }
.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_4:checked ~ .boo_inner { margin-left:-300%; }
.testimonial_slider_2 .boo_inner {
  width:400%;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -moz-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -ms-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -o-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */

  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000); /* easeInOutQuart */
}
.testimonial_slider_2 .slide_content{
  width:25%;
  float:left;
}
.testimonial_slider_2 #controls {
  text-align:center;
}
.testimonial_slider_2 #controls label{
  width:8px;
  height:8px;
  margin:0 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#999; /* Change controls background color */
  border-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
}
.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_1:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(1),
.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_2:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(2),
.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_3:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(3),
.testimonial_slider_2 #slide_2_4:checked ~ #controls label:nth-child(4){
  background:#000; /* Change controls background color when mouse click */
}
.testimonial_2 {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  color: #333; /* Change testimonial paragraph text color */
  padding:30px 30px 23px;
}
.content_2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.content_2:before,
.content_2:after {
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: 19px;
  position: absolute;
}
.content_2:before {
  background: url(icon_testimonial_2_before.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  left: 0;
}
.content_2:after {
  background: url(icon_testimonial_2_after.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
.testimonial_2 p {
  display: inline;
}
.author_2 {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.author_2 h3 {
  color: #333; /* Change author text color */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600px;
  padding: 0 0 5px;
}
.author_2 h4 {
  color: #333; /* Change author text color */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 0 5px;
}
.author_2 h4 a {
  color: #999; /* Change company text link color */
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.author_2 h4 a:after {
  background: #999; /* Change company border link background color */
  height: 1px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 0;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.author_2 h4 a:hover {
  color: #000; /* Change company text link color when mouse over */
  border: none;
}
.author_2 h4 a:hover:after {
  border-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to slider parent div For Ex:

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}


    div#slider { 
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      left: 0;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 0;
      animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
    }
```

Comment: thx vignesh for the code, but where exactly should i place it in my code i provided? plus i want each testimonial to slide for around 7 seconds not 30. it would be great if you can give me the entire code block from start to finish. much appreciated

Comment: @k4r1: Probably anywhere (outside of a `.some-selector{…} ` rule). The order of CSS rules don't matter, unless the selectors are identical. You might want to [edit] http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38241250/edit) your question to include a short HTML excerpt that the CSS is meant to be applied to, in order to make it easier to provide an adequate answer.